# php output javascript all html

Tags: php, html, include, output

Goodday, I am having trouble including css and js files in a PHP file.

Whenever I want to include a js file, the containing script element contains the whole html output.

Same goes for any included stylesheets.

It might be a output problem, but i really dont know what to edit to fix this.

Here is the code,

```
    /* Output*/
    $html                        = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    $html                       .= '<html>';
    $html                       .= '<head>';
    $html                       .= '<title>'.SITE_TITLE.'</title>';
    $html                       .= '<script type="text/javascript">var HLINK = "'.SITE_URL.'/";</script>';
    $html                       .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/core.js"></script>';
    $html                       .= '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/screen.css" />';
    $html                       .= '</head>';


    $html                       .= '<body>';
    $html                       .= '<section id="wrap">';

    switch ($pageurl[0]){
        default               :  $post =   require_once ('pages/homepage.php');  break;
    }

    $html                       .= '<div class="block">';
    $html                       .= 'Doe het<br>';
    $html                       .= '</div>';
    $html                       .= '<pre>';

    $html                       .= $post['post_id'];
    $html                       .= $post['post_title'];
    $html                       .= $post['post_subject'];

    $html                       .= '</pre>';
    $html                       .= '</section>';
    $html                       .= '</body>';
    $html                       .= '</html>';

    echo                           $html;
```

This might be stupid, but i cant figure it out. I appreciate any help.

This is what the browser outputs:

```
<script src="public/js/core.js" type="text/javascript">
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>BLOG</title><script type="text/javascript">var HLINK = "localhost/Ronanversendaal_Dev/";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/core.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/screen.css" /></head><body><section id="wrap"><div class="block">mawfacking doe het<br></div><pre>1Eerste PostTestondwerp</pre></section></body></html>
</script>
```

How do I get it to output just the intended html?

Comment: you don't have a break in your switch statement.

Comment: Doh, didn't see that. But unfortunatly did'nt fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't get output by $post =   require_once ('pages/homepage.php'), you should try following code for store output of file into variable. replace your code line

```
switch ($pageurl[0]){
    default               :  $post =   require_once ('pages/homepage.php');  break;
}
```

with

```
switch ($pageurl[0]){
    default               :  $post =   get_include_contents('pages/homepage.php');  break;
}
```

and here is get_include_contents function.

```
function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}
```